# Inheritance for VBA code in MS Access

Tags: vba, inheritance

I've started to learn VBA in Access. I have read that the language has no inheritance.
And then I read an example code which seems like it actually has inheritance:

```
Dim ctrl As Control

...

If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Then ...
If TypeOf ctrl Is ListBox Then ...
```

It seems to me as the TextBox, ListBox were inherited from the Control. Could somebody explain this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. They are not derived from the `Control` class. They implement `Control`'s definition/ methods and properties signatures. The way `TypeOf` and `Is` operators work it's they check whether the instance of a class Implements one of 3 categories (listed below).

open a **new** workbook

Go to VBE and add

a **class module** and name it: `MyClass`

in the code view only add `Implements MyInterface`

a **class module** and name it: `MyInterface`

in the code view - *do nothing/leave empty*

a **module** and copy paste the below code and run it

```
Sub Main()

    Dim cls As MyClass
    Set cls = New MyClass

    Debug.Print TypeOf cls Is MyClass
    Debug.Print TypeOf cls Is MyInterface

End Sub
```

The result may be surprising

```
True
True
```

`cls` variable *is of two types* - `MyClass` and `MyInterface`

as you can see `cls` doesn't inherit nothing from `MyInterface` but definition. When using `TypeOf` and `Is` it actually shows true because `MyClass` implements `MyInterface`. Not because it's derived from the `MyInterface` class but because it **implements** it.

Now, suppose

```
result = TypeOf objectexpression Is typename
```

The `TypeOf` operator determines whether the run-time type of variable is compatible with *typename*. The compatibility depends on the type category of *typename*. There are three categories

- **Class** *objectexpression* is of type *typename* or inherits from *typename*
- **Structure** *objectexpression* is of type *typename*
- **Interface** *objectexpression* implements *typename* or **inherits from a class that implements** ***typename***

Specifically try to understand the 3rd category - **Interface.**

I think at this point you should really understand why `TypeOf varName Is varType` shows `True` for the `TextBox` and `ListBox`...

When you do VBA inheritance, you can only use **Implements** keyword to 
implements a class **definition**. That is, the class to be implemented is 
equivalent to C++/C#'s **abstract** class: only having property/method 
definition.

Generally, your example isn't a form of a class polymorphism. Class polymorphism occurs when you are actually deriving an instance of one to class to another. This isn't the case. Even though `TextBox` and `ListBox` are both of a `Control` type they aren't actually derived from `Control` class. Note: they may as well be members of another collection - they would be `TypeOf` the higher in the object hierarchy type ( forms, also Component and IComponent becuase Forms implements that).